# Help me beautify this table (mostly w.r.t. spacing)

Tags: tables, spacing, line-spacing

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabu}{
  >{\bfseries\raggedright}p{0.35\linewidth}   
  >{\raggedright         }p{0.35\linewidth}
  >{\raggedright         }p{0.35\linewidth}  
}
\toprule
\rowfont{\bfseries}
      & Patching  & Small-dictionary fitting \\
\midrule
Rationale for use & remove elements inconvenient to compress & keep only elements inconveient to compress \\
Intended scope of application & minimum necessary & maximum possible \\
Number of elements remaining to compress after application & the full column's length   & less than full column length (hopefully much less) \\
Elements inconveient to compress reside in & the smaller subcolumn & the smaller subcolumn \\
Compression ratio of affected data & very poor (worse than uncompressed) & very good (probably better than rest of data) \\
Potential for overhead & per each patched position & per each original column element \\
Repeat application & useless & relevant, possibly even with same-or-lower width \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Things I don't like:

- inter-row spacing is higher than inter-cell spacing, making it seem as though rows break when they don't and vice-versa
- I would rather not have to manually fiddle with the column widths and the scaling factor manually
- There's plenty of space underneath the `\midrule`, but almost no space above the `\bottomrule`

What should I do to make it look better? (Feel free to make suggestions beyond my dislikes, including purely "code beautification" suggestions.)

Comment: The spacing of `\bottomrule` is caused by `tabu`, use `tabular` and drop the `\rowfont` (the only feature used from `tabu`) and add the `\bfseries` to the two cells. After that, the spacing should be better.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid `\resizebox` for fitting a table in the text area.

You can use `X` columns, instead of guessing the widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\small % if you prefer
\begin{tabu}{
  @{}
  >{\bfseries\RaggedRight}X<{\unskip\strut}
  >{\RaggedRight         }X<{\unskip\strut}
  >{\RaggedRight         }X<{\unskip\strut}
  @{}
}
\toprule
      & \bfseries Patching  & \bfseries Small-dictionary fitting \\
\midrule
Rationale for use &
  remove elements inconvenient to compress &
  keep only elements inconvenient to compress \\
\addlinespace
Intended scope of application &
  minimum necessary &
  maximum possible \\
\addlinespace
Number of elements remaining to compress after application &
  the full column's length &
  less than full column length (hopefully much less) \\
\addlinespace
Elements inconvenient to compress reside in &
  the smaller subcolumn &
  the smaller subcolumn \\
\addlinespace
Compression ratio of affected data &
  very poor (worse than uncompressed) &
  very good (probably better than rest of data) \\
\addlinespace
Potential for overhead &
  per each patched position &
  per each original column element \\
\addlinespace
Repeat application &
  useless &
  relevant, possibly even with same-or-lower width \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks slightly better (but I don't know what you meant with the inter row vs. inter cell spacing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{%
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  >{\bfseries\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash         }X
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash         }X
}
\toprule
      & \bfseries Patching  & \bfseries Small-dictionary fitting \\
\midrule
Rationale for use & remove elements inconvenient to compress & keep only elements inconveient to compress \\
Intended scope of application & minimum necessary & maximum possible \\
Number of elements remaining to compress after application & the full column's length   & less than full column length (hopefully much less) \\
Elements inconveient to compress reside in & the smaller subcolumn & the smaller subcolumn \\
Compression ratio of affected data & very poor (worse than uncompressed) & very good (probably better than rest of data) \\
Potential for overhead & per each patched position & per each original column element \\
Repeat application & useless & relevant, possibly even with same-or-lower width \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]